# escape character used in grep

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

```
sh-4.3$ grep "hi +hello"                                                                                                                                                        
sh-4.3$ grep "hi +hello" test                                                                                                                                                   
sh-4.3$ grep "hi \+hello" test                                                                                                                                                  
hi hello                                                                                                                                                                        
hi  hello                                                                                                                                                                       
sh-4.3$ grep "hi *hello" test                                                                                                                                                   
hi hello                                                                                                                                                                        
hihello                                                                                                                                                                         
hi  hello                                                                                                                                                                       
sh-4.3$
```

In the above code, escape character is required with '+' regex character, but while using '*' regex character escape character is not required.

Can anyone explain the reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard GNU `grep` recognises BRE (basic regular expressions) and `*` is an original metacharacter in BRE while `+` is an extension to BRE. For `+` to be recognised as a metacharacter in BRE, it must be escaped. However, if you tell `grep` to use ERE (extended regular expressions) by using the `-E` flag, you do not need to escape any metacharacter (if you escape them, they will become literals instead). [There's a bit of explanation in the grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Basic-vs-Extended) and [here's a more detailed overview](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)

```
$ grep -E 'hi +hello' test
hi hello
hi  hello
```

You can also use `egrep`

```
$ egrep 'hi +hello' test
hi hello
hi  hello
```

I decide whether to use BRE or ERE based on the total number of backslashes I will have to type...

Comment: so in this case escape character is working the other way around, instead of treating it as a literal , escape character makes the shell to read it as regex character. am i ryt..?

Comment: @PankajPandey exactly right, in BRE.

Comment: how would i know whether i am using standard GNU or any other variant, is there any command to know that.. ?

Comment: @PankajPandey this is about knowing the tools you are working with. It is not part of your environment but part of `grep`. If you use standard `grep` in Ubuntu, you use BRE, unless you use the `-E` flag. Other tools that recognise regex have similar features, for example `sed` has an `-r` flag to use ERE but `-E` also works. Check the `man` page for the command for this kind of info.